# Get confusion while using "Array. Map" method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My code is :

```
let obj1 = [
    { city: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan' },
    { city: 'Bangkok', country: 'Thailand'}
];
function myFunc(arr, key, value){
    let newArr = arr.map((e)=>{
       let obj = e;
       obj[key] = value;
       return obj;
    })
    return newArr
}

console.log(myFunc(obj1, 'continent', 'Asia'));
console.log(obj1);
```

I don't want to mutate the "obj1" array. That's why I'm using Array.map method. But it still changing the original Array. Does anyone know why this happening? Where I made the mistake?

Comment: Because objects are reference types. Do like `let obj = Object.assign({},e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You thought that using the equal operator will copy each object in array
so you don't mutate the object

```js
let obj = e;
```

but what you have in code is another reference to the same item(s) in array.

`map` itself is not a gurantee you have immutable data structure, you have to correctly copy the data,
for objects in `js` you can use either `Object.assign` or the `spread operater`

```js
  let obj = { ...e };
  // or
  let obj = Object.assign({}, e);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a new object and spread the old one.

```js
function myFunc(arr, key, value){
    return  arr.map(e => ({ ...e, [key]: value }));
}

let obj1 = [{ city: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan' }, { city: 'Bangkok', country: 'Thailand'}];

console.log(myFunc(obj1, 'continent', 'Asia'));
console.log(obj1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```